# Get Rule name in "then" clause in drools

Tags: drools

Is it possible to retrieve rule name in the then clause of drool rule?

```
rule "A"
    when
        ---
    then
        // something that outputs "A"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, in then clause you may use expression:

```
drools.getRule().getName()
```

Answer (score 4):

As Cyril said, you can get the rule name in the then clause by calling drools.getRule().getName() of the drools rule.

Just a little more info, you can check the getName() method in Rule Interface in the following api:
 http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.1/javadocs/org/drools/definition/rule/Rule.html